# Wordpress - problems with get_blog_option() in mulsitite network

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Multisite Network and in each blog I have a Dashboard Plugin where I can set some blog infos like logo_path. I set these values with:

```
update_blog_option($blog_id, "logo_path", $logo_path);
```

works like a charme.

But now I want to feature some of the blogs on the frontpage og my network root page. I queried my blogs with:

```
wp_get_sites()
```

and get an array with all blogs. Now I want to create a new array only with blogs which have a special value (logo_path). But if I try to get the options with:

```
get_blog_option($blog_id,"logo_path");
```

it returns nothing. I could only get fixed values like

```
get_blog_option($blog_id,"admin_email");
```

Could anybody give me a hint?
Thank you!